# Getting a java.lang.Class with generics

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I'm a C# guy learning Java and I'm trying to understand how generics work in Java.

Given a class or interface "SomeThing", I know I can do this to get the Class of that type:

```
Something.class
```

Now, given a generic interface

I'd love to write

```
(GenericInterface<SomeClass>).class
```

but the compiler doesn't like that much.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you attempting to determine what class SomeClass is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because, thanks to erasure, there *isn't* a `GenericInterface<SomeClass>` class.  There's just a `GenericInterface` class, which has a generic parameter.

If you want it so that you can call generically type-safe methods such as `Class.cast()` or `Class.newInstance()`, then you're out of luck.  Generics are essentially a compile-time concept; there isn't enough information available at runtime to perform the generic checks, and so these methods *can't* be type-safe for an arbitrary `Class` instance.

The best you can do in this case is use the "raw" `GenericInterface.class`, then explicitly cast the results into `GenericInterface<SomeClass>` immediately afterwards.  This will correctly give an "unchecked" warning, since as mentioned above there is no runtime check that the object really has the right generic parameter, and the JVM just has to take your word for it.

(Along the same lines, if you're trying to perform some sort of `instanceof` check, then that's simply not possible either.  An *object* doesn't have a generic parameter to its class; only the variables you assign it to do.  So again, these runtime checks just plain aren't possible due to the design constraints of the language.)

Answer (score 2):

Generics are fundamentally different in Java and C#, because in Java generics are checked at compile-time but then changed to the concrete class in a process known as **type erasure**. Using your example, `GenericInterface<SomeClass>` becomes `GenericInterface` at runtime.

It's a slightly half-assed implementation of generics, and as you're seeing it does present some problems (which you can usually work around). It was done that way to maintain backwards-compatibility with older versions of Java.

Comment: It's not half-assed, it's less restrictive. In a way it happens to open up more possibilities for dynamic languages that run on the JVM. Constructs which the CLR simply cannot do. So my point is: It's just a matter of perspective.

Answer (score 0):

No, Java Generics don't work that way.

You can do `GenericInterface.class` to get at the non-generic root class, but there is no separate class for the generic version.